# What moveset should my Skitty have to be useful?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-black-2-white-2

I wan't to keep [Skitty](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Skitty_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) in my main team for the majority of the game, but I'd like to know what moves should I teach or remove in order to make it as useful as possible?

If it matters I'm going to be playing Pokemon White 2.

Comment: Honestly, you should consider not using Skitty. Delcatty has [almost no redeeming qualities](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/delcatty), even compared to other Pokemon in the NU tier (the lowest tier), according to Smogon. While you can have fun playing with any Pokemon in the game, if your primary goal is to have a *useful* Pokemon, Skitty/Delcatty aren't going to make the cut. If you do keep it, prepare for a grind.

Comment: @StrixVaria Well I'm not planning on playing competitively. I'm just talking about casual game play. I know that some more "professional" players may scuff at what I'm about to say, but I play with Skitty, because I like the Pokemon and that's about all there is to it. Basically I just keep Skitty in my team, because she is a fun Pokemon (normally) to play with. Long story short: I'm much more of a casual player than I am a competitive one.

Comment: It seems like you're primarily interested in SINGLEplayer, whereas @StrixVaria is thinking in terms of multiplayer.

Comment: I realize that Smogon is a source of competetitive information, but the point I was making is that Delcatty is *not good*. Can you have fun with a Pokemon that is not good? Absolutely. I play through all the time using low tier Pokemon. You are asking, however, how to make Skitty *useful*, and if that is your end goal, you might not be able to reach it, even just in the single player campaign.

Comment: In my opinion, the campaign is so easy that you can hammer through 90% of it with most any team of 6, as long as you have decent type coverage.

Comment: @StrixVaria Also "Honestly, you should consider not using Skitty. Delcatty has almost no redeeming qualities" I'm not sure if you realized this or not, but I don't plan on using Delcatty, but just Skitty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The moves you teach it may largely depend on what ability your Skitty has;

---

## [Normalize](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Normalize_%28Ability%29)

This ability will give all of Skitty's attacks Same-type attack bonus, so priority moves like [Sucker Punch](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sucker_Punch_%28move%29) (must be bred in) can get a little extra power behind their speed. It will also let Skitty use moves like [Thunder Wave](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Thunder_Wave_%28move%29) (TM73) on the otherwise immune ground types.

A downside to normalize is that ghost types will be immune to all your direct damage - this can be mitigated using [Foresight](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Foresight_%28move%29) (learned at lvl4). Additionally, Rock and Steel types will be highly resistant to your attacks.

---

## [Cute Charm](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cute_Charm_%28Ability%29) or [Wonder Skin](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wonder_Skin_%28Ability%29) (hidden ability)

[Zen Headbutt](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Zen_Headbutt_%28move%29) (must be bred in) is a good counter to normal types' greatest weakness - fighting. High priority moves like the previously mentioned Sucker Punch or [Fake Out](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fake_Out_%28move%29) (move relearner) are still a good choice.

Skitty can also learn [Baton Pass](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Baton_Pass_%28move%29) and [Wish](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wish_%28move%29) though breeding - combined with [Calm Mind](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Calm_Mind_%28move%29) (TM04), this can make for a fairly decent support (combine those three with a special attack like Ice Beam (TM13) or Thunderbolt (TM24) to let skitty take advantage of its own stat boosts.

---

[Smogon University](http://www.smogon.com/bw/pokemon/skitty) goes into further details on specific builds, giving suggested EVs, natures, and items as well as strategies. You can copy those movesets to the letter, or modify them to your liking.

---

**EDIT**: If you are looking solely to teach moves to an existing Skitty, and not do any fancy breeding;

- Swagger (TM87) and Psych Up (TM77) have an interesting, if risky, dynamic - Confuse the target, raise its attack two stages, and then copy the attack up buff. To make use of this buff, Return (TM27) is a good STAB move that has a base power of 102 at maximum friendship, and round it out with Faint Attack (lvl 29) for a little type coverage.
- You could try for Sing (lvl 11), Dream Eater (TM85), and Wakeup Slap (lvl 32) - but sing's low accuracy makes this a risky strategy.
- Toxic (TM06) - if you aren't fighting a steel or poison type this strategy can work wonders, poison them with toxic and then *stall* - Protect (TM17) Double Team (TM32), and for a fourth move Attract (TM45) or Swagger
- Para-fusion - the idea here is to minimise the enemy's chance to do anything useful and hit themselves Thunder Wave (TM73) and Swagger should set it up nicely - The danger to using swagger (particularly after several applications to keep the enemy confused) is that if they manage to get by both statuses (37.5%, I believe) and actually hit you it will **HURT** - You might consider Double Team to make yourself even harder to hit.
- Heal Bell (lvl 39) could be worked in to many of the above possibilities - it's a nice team support ability to clear the rest of your team's status ailments - particularly useful during some of the longer routes, means you don't have to be too vigilant about stocking up on the various curative items that may be in short supply and on the pricy side. (although by lvl 39 the cost and availability of the items may no longer be an issue)
- If you go for Calm Mind to buff your SpAtk, Echoed Voice's (TM49) power increases by 40 with each application (up to 200), and it's normal, so STAB bonus applies. If your Skitty is durable enough to survive a few hits it could build up quite nicely against trainers with more than two pokemon.

And if this is just against the NPC's throughout the story, always remember that there's nothing a little back-tracking and grinding out a few levels won't cure.

Comment: From what I'm getting a few of these moves can only be gotten via breeding. As for Wonderskin how can I tell if Skitty has it or not?

Comment: @Scootaloo - Wonder Skin is a normal ability, it will show up in the same way.  It's "hidden" in the sense that you can't catch a Skitty with it, you'd have to get one from the Dream World.

Comment: @Scootaloo Edited in a few options that don't require any breeding. Just keep in mind typing and a few abilities could shut down some of them. And that any that rely on status effects can be easily undone by some trainers, many gym leaders, all of the Elite 4, and potentially by whatever berry the enemy Pokemon is holding.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Nice answer dude. Very thorough

Comment: Wonder Skin actually worked on things like Whirlwind in the original BW, which would make it nice on the Baton Pass sets. Don't know if that's still the case in B2W2 though.

Comment: @GraceNote Should still work - Wonderskin reduces the accuracy of a '[status move](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_move)' down to 50% - and there's a great many moves listed as "[status](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Category:Status_moves)" category

Comment: @GraceNote Baton Pass sets?

Comment: @Scootaloo Sets that use Baton Pass to move status boosts from Skitty to another mon. It's under the section that's for Wonder Skin already. I just wanted to highlight that particular aspect of Wonder Skin as a very nice bonus towards that direction.

Comment: @GraceNote Cool. Well I can't wait to get Pokemon White 2 then :). Could you also remove my flag please? it wasn't needed (bad choice on my part).

Answer (score 2):

You guys are crazy, I run Skitty in competitive VGC and it does fine.

For doubles:

- Fake out
- Helping Hand
- Thunder Wave
- and a preference move suited to your team.

Give it an Eviolite, max it's HP and defense and I guarantee he'll be useful.

In single battles run:

- Baton Pass
- Cosmic power
- Wish
- Protect

This is a simple cleric build but 90% of the time you wall Pokemon very easily. I've walled Garchomps, Dragonites, Cresselias, anything short of Focus Blast Mega Alakazam I've had little trouble setting up on.

Good luck!

Side Note: Purrloin is another great option. Similar idea, but run

- Foul Play
- Yawn
- Attract
- and preference move

Prankster really helps here and Purrloin outclasses Thunderus defense wise. Foul play has the possibility of 1hko-ing Landorus, Metagross and most base 150 attack pokemon. Just another useful cat for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that some small bits of your answer are exclusive to Gen6 (Cosmic power doesn't seem to be a breeding move for skitty before Gen6), and this question was about Gen5. Additionally, the OP seemed to want to keep an existing Skitty, so breeding was out. In either case, some of these tips are useful - but keep in mind Skitty's stats are *objectively* bad, being in a 3-way tie for the 47th lowest stats. If you are walling anything, it is primarily through priority damage nullification moves, that would work just as well if not better on something with the same moves but better stats.

Answer (score 2):

I use Skitty as a support Pokemon.

I'd put

- Fake out (for flinch)
- Protect
- Something with priority
- Thunder Wave if you have normalize, otherwise swap it with Helping Hand.

But be prepared for quick knockouts.

Comment: Whilst Helping hand is useful, it's usefulness is limited to double battles. Doubles isn't a huge point in Singleplayer mode, and with most of the major battles (Gyms, Team/Faction Bosses, Elite Four/Champ and Rival) being Singles, you'd be better off running a different move.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that Skitty isn't a good pokémon, the best way is to use Choice Specs. This has the disadvantage that you can only use one attack, but this one will be more powerful (increased by 50%).

By TMs, you can teach:

- Ice Beam
- Thunderbolt
- Shadow Ball
- Grass Knot

Cute Charm would be better here, 4 normal attacks are useless. In general, normal attacks are not useful, because there are no types it's effective against.

The best nature is Modest, but you can't influence it anymore.

Comment: I'd argue that thunderbolt is largely superfluous with the type coverage Ice Beam and Grass Knot provide - if you don't mind steel being the one type the Skitty cannot adequately deal with - Switching it out for Echoed Voice, you could start outperforming the typed moves against Normal/Fire/Fight/poison/elec/ice/bug/dark (and water types under 50kg) by *the second attack*, and from there you can go on to sweep.

Comment: @TrentHawkins even though this was supposed to help me I'm still not sure which moves to pick. There are quite a few choices.

Comment: Normal attacks are surprisingly useful, such as Return and Extremespeed. Return has very good, reliable damage (which is amplified by STAB) and Extremespeed/Quick Attack are priority attacks (which are always useful).