# Is there a way to get the "Wonder Skin" ability without having access to the Dream World?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, emulation

I'm interested in getting a few (actually all) Pokemon with the "Wonder Skin" ability. However I've recently learned that I'd need to have access to the Dream World in order to do this:

> Wonder Skin is a normal ability, it will show up in the same way. **It's "hidden" in the sense that you can't catch a Skitty with it, you'd have to get one from the Dream World.** – [Shinrai (via my previous question)](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118837/what-moveset-should-my-skitty-have-to-be-useful#comment160045_118847)

> Oh... my... I just looked it up, just getting a Skitty with Wonder Skin to appear in the dreamworld requires 10000 **dreamworld points** >.< That's a lot of grinding. – [Trent Hawkins (via The Bridge)](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=9695404#9695404)

The problem here is I'm using an emulator (DeSmuME 0.9.9) with my **legally dumped rom**. As of right now Wi-Fi is not supported for DeSmuME and won't be for the foreseeable future (according to what I've read on forums and on the main site) and the Dream World requires access to it. I could use a program like PokeGen (a program that modifies save files) and give myself one, but I'd like to play the game legitimately.

*Also no this question does not violate the rules, because I own an actual copy of Pokemon White 2 (where I got the rom from) and I'm not asking for cheats*.

Long Story Short: is there anyway for me to get the "Wonder Skin" ability without having access to the Dream World?

Comment: If you have an actual DS as well as the hardware and software for reading/writing the ROM, you might be able to work around this by copying your save back to the original game cartridge (so you don't lose your progress) and then playing the dream world on the DS.

Comment: I'll look into that. There should be a way for me to export my DeSmuME save file. Not sure if it'll work out though.

Comment: On second thought, I think the save games don't actually get stored in the cartridge on the DS...but I tracked down what seems to be the go-to guide for backing up and restoring DS save games [here](http://projectpokemon.org/forums/showthread.php?16601-How-to-Backup-Restore-your-retail-cartridge-save-file-(D-P-Pt-HG-SS-B-W-Nearly-any-other-DS-game)...whether and how it can be done seems to depend on your DS model.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock thanks. Also I'm almost positive that *most* games  (NDS wise) save to the cartridge. If this doesn't work out (which hopefully it does) I can always edit the save.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Bulbapedia, there are 4 Pokemon with the ability Wonder Skin.

Sigilyph's Slot 1 ability is Wonder Skin, so you do not need Dream World access for this.

However, with Venomoth, Skitty, and Delcatty, for whom Wonder Skin is a hidden ability, this is more difficult.

In Pokemon Black 2/White 2, there are only a few sources of Pokemon with hidden abilities that do not involve connectivity to the 3DS (Dream Radar), or the Nintendo servers (Wi-Fi/Global Link Event, Dream World).

For future reference, in case another Dream World ability catches your eye, you can obtain these Pokemon through:

- [Hidden Grottoes](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hidden_Grotto)
- Finding N's Pokemon
- In-game Event
- Breeding

Venonat can be found in the Hidden Grotto on Route 3 (Pond). Evolving Venonat will give you a Venomoth with Wonder Skin.

However, neither Skitty nor Delcatty can be found in Hidden Grottoes, nor do the in-game events contain their Dream World variants (Such events include the recurring Braviary on Route 4, and Musharna in the Dreamyard). N's Pokemon can only be caught if you performed a memory link with a previous game (difficult to do without using the physical White 2), but it appears that N did not have Skitty nor Delcatty.

The last legal/legitimate option in this case would be to breed a fresh Skitty. However, since the Pokemon cannot be obtained any other ways, this is a bit of a  Catch 22. But if you would like some peace of mind about using "Genetically Modified Pokemon", you can utilize save editing software to give yourself a temporary female Dream World variant to breed, and then release it afterwards, keeping the eggs. Because most Dream World Pokemon arrive in the Entralink at Lv 10, hatching a Pokemon at a low level would probably feel more legitimate.

Save restoration through the link given above by Theodore is also a good idea. I would suggest that perhaps you enable Memory Link on your physical copy after dumping your save file onto it, to allow for N's Pokemon to be caught when you play on your emulator again.

Finally, a full list of Dream World variants and their in-game locations can be found [here](http://www.serebii.net/games/hiddenabilityaccess.shtml).

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the info. :). You'll probably fit in very well here.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot about Venonat's appearance in Route 3's Hidden Grotto. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you have to have access to dreamworld. unless you cheat